# Python Tkinter Shutdown

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on an embedded device GUI and have a simple two button screen working, which has restart and shutdown (e.g. poweroff).

The restart command works fine, but I am having trouble with the shutdown command. I have tried "sudo shutdown", "sudo poweroff", "sudo halt" etc and none have any impact.

When I issue these commands at the terminal they work fine, but when issued through the GUI they do not work :(.

Is there any trick to getting these to work?

```
    def restart(p1):
       os.system("shutdown -t 0 -r -f")

    def shutdown(p1):
       os.system("sudo shutdown")
```

Comment: `shutdown -P now`?

Comment: no luck with any of those for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this----

```
def shutdown()
     os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```